# How to handle unexpected ad popup in hdfc site?

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate HDFC website. While entering there is an ad popup,which sometimes come and sometimes don't. I want to handle it using try catch. Please help with this.

Comment: i can handle it by locating X and  by clicking but in case it don't popup it will throw nosuchelementexception.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to first see if the element is present, act accordingly it is, else continue on as normal. You could do the following and evaluate the true/false returned by the function :)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath,wait):
    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,(xpath)))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```